# Incluir aspas em valor de variável String

Tags: string, vb.net

Gostaria de saber como faço para declarar uma variável do tipo String em que o valor possui aspas no Visual Basic .net?

Por exemplo:

```
Public frase As String = "E ele disse: -"Olá a todos!""
```

Existe alguma expressão de escape para o Visual Basic entenda que as aspas no valor da variável fazem parte do valor, e não estão finalizando a declaração da variável?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma de incluir aspas duplas como texto numa `String` em Visual Basic é colocando duas seguidas, assim `""`.

O seu código de exemplo deve passar a ser:

```
Public frase As String = "E ele disse: -""Olá a todos!"""
```

[Veja este exemplo no .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jRRLaB)

[Pode também ver um exemplo deste padrão na documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Sim, existe uma forma.
Você deve usar \ antes das "
Por Exemplo:

```
String Frase = " O cachorro é \"BRAVO\"  ";
```

Comment: Não existe `\"` em Visual Basic. [Veja um exemplo da documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

O mais simples é usar a representação ANSI para aspas duplas: `Chr$(34)`.

Exemplo1:

Código1:

```
Debug.Print wsh.CodeName & ".Range(" & Chr$(34) & Loc.Address & Chr$(34) & ")"
```

Resultado1: `Planilha1.Range("$A$1")`

Exemplo2:

Código2:

```
Debug.Print Chr$(34) & "Olá Mundo" & Chr$(34)
```

Resultado2: `"Olá Mundo"`

Obs.: É possível declarar uma variável para isso também caso queira:

```
         ExemploAspasDuplas = Chr$(34)
```

Referência: [Incluir uma variável que representa aspas - docs.microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/access/concepts/criteria-expressions/include-quotation-marks-in-string-expressions#include-a-variable-representing-quotation-marks)